# Trying to get the routeName but it's always empty

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I tried to get the routeName from the URL because i need to set another class in the Layout of the body if i'm on the /Category page.

[image]

```
  @{string classContent = Request.QueryString["routeName"] != "/Category" ? "container" : "";}; 
  <div id="Content" class="body-wrapper @classContent">
```

My problem is, Request.QueryString["routeName"] is always empty and couldn't find why.

Does someone know why it's always empty or has a better approach for setting a different class if you're on a certain page?

Comment: Have you logged the result of Request.QueryString? Seems to me it should be empty because there is no query string on the URL you have shown.

Comment: You're absolutely right i have mistaken some thinks in my question and posted the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the end i solved it with that code:

```
   var segments = Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Split(new[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
   string classContent = "container";
   if (segments.Count() > 1) { classContent = segments[1] != "category" ? "" : "container";}
```

Request.Url.AbsolutePath gets the whole URL.

[image]

After that i split the whole URL and save it into a list.

Then i test if the list is long enough to be on another site except home.

In the end i look if the second part of the url is /Category and save the Css class appropriate to the output of the url.